# Print new <div> on id iteration change inside php while loop from MySQL result

Tags: php, html, mysql, while-loop

I have this `MySQL` table:

```
+------------+-------------+
| contact_id | _company_id |
+------------+-------------+
|          1 |           1 |
|          2 |           1 |
|          3 |           1 |
|          4 |           2 |
|          5 |           2 |
+------------+-------------+
```

Im trying to print a new `<div>` containing all rows with the same `_company_id`

So far I have this code:

```
$previous = '';

while ($result = $stmt->fetch()) {

    $current = $_company_id;

    //This should be executed every first iteration and every time $_company_id changes
    if ($current != $previous) { $html .= '<div id="company-' . $_company_id . '" class="tab-pane fade">'; }

    //Iterate all contact_id here with the same _company_id

    if ($current != $previous) { $html .= '</div>'; }

    $previous = $current;

}
```

My desired output is:

```
<div id="company-1" class="tab-pane fade">123</div>
<div id="company-2" class="tab-pane fade">45</div>
```

Right now the output is:

```
<div id="company-1" class="tab-pane fade">1</div>
23
<div id="company-2" class="tab-pane fade">4</div>
5
```

What should I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$previous = null;

while ($result = $stmt->fetch()) {

    $current = $_company_id;

    //This should be executed every first iteration and every time $_company_id changes
    if ($current !== $previous) {
      if($previous !== null)
        $html.='</div>';
      $html .= '<div id="company-' . $_company_id . '" class="tab-pane fade">';
    }

    //Iterate all contact_id here with the same _company_id

    $previous = $current;

}

if($previous!==null)
  $html.='</div>';
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand why this part `if($previous !== null) $html.='</div>';` does not output `</div>` at the very first iteration? At the first iteration the variable `$previous` is equal to `null` (right?). Your code works fine, but I can't figure out why! Would you please explain that part? Thank's

Comment: First we set $previous to null - it's say we not opened any div. When we have new company, we check $previous. If $previous is null, then we not opened any div and don't need close anything. If $previous not null, then we already opened div and must close him. In end of code we check again, because if we opened div his don't close in iteration. I hope it is clear, in spite of my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your SQL query and/or some more code in this example. Off the top of my head, you could do something like:

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=companies","root","root");
$sql = "select _company_id from table_name limit 0,30;";
$companies = $dbh->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($companies as $company){
    $contacts_sql = "select contact_id from table_name where company_id = :company_id";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(":company_id", $company['_company_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $contacts = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo "<div id='company-{$company['_company_id']}'>";
    foreach($contacts as $contact){
        echo $contact['contact_id'];        
    }
    echo "</div>".PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

Could you not?