# Trying to figure out why this PHP while loop actually works

Tags: php, html, mysql, loops, while-loop

This question is based on a reply I got from a question I submitted earlier:

[Print new <div> on id iteration change inside php while loop from MySQL result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26454774/print-new-div-on-id-iteration-change-inside-php-while-loop-from-mysql-result)

It's not really a problem, but I'm trying to understand what's going on.

I can't figure out why this loop does not add `</div>` to the variable `$html` at the very first iteration when `$previous` is equal to `null`

```
$previous = null;

while ($result = $stmt->fetch()) {

    if ($_company_id !== $previous) {
        if($previous !== null) {
            $html .='</div>';
        }
        $html .= '<div id="company-' . $_company_id . '" class="tab-pane fade">';
    }

    $previous = $_company_id;

}

if($previous != null) {
    $html.='</div>';
}
```

The output is exactly as I want it:

```
<div id="company-1" class="tab-pane fade"></div>
<div id="company-2" class="tab-pane fade"></div>
```

But I just can't understand why. Can anyone please explain this to me?

Comment: Because `$previous` is `NULL` on first iteration.

Comment: Try to change `!==` to `!=`

Comment: I don't get this code, where are you setting `$_company_id`?

Comment: @DaveChen `$_company_id` is a variable from `$stmt->bind_result()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually because they check IF IS NOT. Take a closer look at

```
 if($previous !== null) {
   $html .='</div>';
 }
```

So it gets skipped on the first go through. On Every other Turn it has a value and the condition is true. hence executing the code.

Comment: Ahh, I get it now... Been staring me blind on the code but I get it now. Also I feel a bit stupid. Thank's anyway!

Comment: @David You're welcome. Sometimes a little distance helps to see the obviouse.